# Dependency issue with System.Net.Http and ASP.NET 5 on OS X

Tags: macos, mono, coreclr, asp.net5

I am trying to create first sample application running with ASP.NET 5 on OS X. However I just can't figure out how project.json dependencies work. 
I generated Web Api Application with yeoman and everything had worked fine until I've tried to use WebClient. 
According to dnvm list I'm running:

```
*    1.0.0-rc1-update2    mono                 linux/osx
```

And while restore packages goes well the project fails at build step.
Here is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "LocationService"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Web.Http": "4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {


    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

And project fails on build with unresolved reference:

```
LocationService/Controllers/ValuesController.cs(32,40):
DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0246: The type or namespace name
'WebClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference?)
```

I've tried add dependency both under dnxcore50 and dnx451. 
Dmvm tells me that I can use coreclr x64 but it seems just not works in my case - ends up with numerous unresolved references during build.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient is not available (yet?) for dnxcore.

Try removing dnxcore50 framework or use HttpClient or HttpWebRequest instead of WebClient.